Docker CORS Error, and how to expose docker container to local network
I have 2 questions regarding docker-compose, i am fairly new to docker and docker-compose. i copied docker files and docker compose.yaml files from a tutorial figured out how to build the containers but then i keep getting CORS error between the frontend and backend. by the way when i run it in dev mode in my local machine in vscode ( npm run dev ) it works fine with no CORS error.
2 question is : how can i expose the docker containers to the network because i want to access the website in home from different computers connected to the same network.
# Stage-1 & specify a name 'builder'
FROM  node:latest AS builder

# Create a directory  and go to the directory 
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json file to my current directory to install the necessary dependence  
COPY package.json .

# Install the dependence
RUN npm install

# Copy other files to my current directory
COPY . .

# Build and optimize static file
RUN npm run build

# Stage-2
FROM nginx:latest

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# Copy the static file to my Nginx folder to serve static contain
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# Open the port to react
EXPOSE 5173

# Run nginx in the foreground
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
      include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
      default_type  application/octet-stream;
      sendfile        on;
      keepalive_timeout  65;

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
}

# Select a base image
FROM  node:20-alpine3.17

# Create a directory  and go to the directory 
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json file to my current directory to install the necessary dependence  
COPY package.json .

# Install the dependence
RUN npm install

# Copy other files to my current directory
COPY . .


# Open the port for the express server
EXPOSE 3000

# Run express rum in the foreground
# Run express rum in the foreground and bind to 0.0.0.0
CMD ["npm", "run", "start", "--", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]

version: '3.8'

# Services
services:
  # Server service
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: server
    ports:
    - "0.0.0.0:3000:3000" # Bind to all network interfaces
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:admin@db/database
    depends_on:
      - db

  # Client service
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: client
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    depends_on:
      - server

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:              # Add environment variable for PostgreSQL
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/opt/postgres/data



Does the setup in "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend work for you?  In your setup, add a path to the Nginx configuration in the front-end that proxy_pass http://server:3000, and use a path-only URL in the client.  Now you're not crossing from one server to another, there is not a cross-origin call, and CORS rules don't apply.

@DavidMaze it doesn't work with proxy pass in the nginx conf file, still CORS problem
